# Howto deserialize class, if class version was changed

Tags: java, serialization, versioning, classloader

I want to write the code, that can deserialize the class even if the class was changed (but you have old class version).

The idea is simple.

1. Read the `serialVersionUID` of the serialized class
2. Check if that `serialVersionUID` is equal to the `serialVersionUID` of the current class version.
3. If not, create new `ClassLoader` and load the old class version into workspace.

I thought to use something like this:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filename);
ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(file) {
    protected Class<?> resolveClass(java.io.ObjectStreamClass desc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        //5639490496474438904L is the suid of the older version
        if (desc.getSerialVersionUID() == 5639490496474438904L) {
            Class c01 = null;
            URL eineURL = new URL("file://localhost/U:/MyJavaProj/bin/test/oldversion/");
            URL[] reiURL = new URL[] {eineURL};
            URLClassLoader clazLader = new URLClassLoader(reiURL);
            c01 = clazLader.loadClass("test.SerObj");
            return c01; 
        }
        return super.resolveClass(desc);
    }
};

SerObj obj = (SerObj) o.readObject();
```

The problem is in the last line. My current class version is placed in **U:/MyJavaProj/bin/test/SerObj.class**
My old class version is placed in **U:/MyJavaProj/bin/test/oldversion/test/SerObj.class**

In the last line I read the old class version but cast it to the new version :(

Has anyone some idea or maby any other aproach to add the versioning support for the serialization in Java?

Comment: What exactly is the problem - can you provide an exception stack trace?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: test.SerObj cannot be cast to test.SerObj :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to perform the cast in the last line, because it's of a different class (which is not castable) - you might get a confusing message such as `test.SerObj is not an instance of test.SerObj`.

This arises from the fact that a class is essentially a `java.lang.Class` instance, which critically *is unique within a given classloader*.  Even if you referenced the exact same `*.class` file, an instance of `SerObj` loaded by the default classloader is a different class from an instance of `SerObj` loaded by `clazLader`.  Neither class could be cast to the other one.

Thus it is not going to be possible for the method to return `SerObj` if you need to use multiple classloaders to deserialise.  (Besides - how could it, when the two class files could have arbitrary differences?)

---

One possible workaround is to define an interface that defines the behaviour which is fixed between versions of the class.  If you set up the temporary classloader such that it can *only* load `SerObj` from the oldversion class file, and that it has the right parent classloader, then your old `SerObj` should still implement the interface class as defined by the root classloader.

In this was, both the new `SerObj` and old `SerObj` instances would be castable to the `SerObjIface` interface, and so you could declare your method to return *that*.  And in fact if you want callers to deal with different yet similar classes (which is what different versions of "the same class" are), you should arguably be returning an interface for this anyway.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same idea with an interface, but it was interesting to know, if i could solve it another way.

Comment: But it looks, like to cast into common interface or parent class is one and only solution.

Comment: Yep - as the classes are different, they can only possibly share a parent interface or superclass (in the extreme case, all the way up to `java.lang.Object`).  I don't think it's conceptually possible to get around this limitation.

Comment: You could use reflection to read the fields from the old class and set those on an instance of the new class.

Answer (score 4):

i don't know if you trying to fix an existing problem, or write new functionality.  if the latter, then i would look into using the advanced functionality of java serialization.  java serialization supports various facilities for being able to handle multiple serial versions of the same class within one classloader (critically, though, you need to keep the serialVersionUID the *same* for all instances).

here's an example for handling an "incompatible" change, where an integer value was changed to a String value:

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final int CUR_VERSION = 5;
  private String _value;

  private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) {
    // first value is always the serial version:
    int dataVersion = in.readInt();
    if(dataVersion == CUR_VERSION) {
      // _value is a String
      _value = in.readString();
    } else {
      // in older versions, _value was an int
      _value = String.valueOf(in.readInt());
    }
  }

  private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream out) {
    // always write version first
    out.writeInt(CUR_VERSION);
    out.writeString(_value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I know this solution. But it would not work by some serialisation incompatibaly changes. And that is, what i want to support

Comment: not true.  you can certainly handle incompatible changes, you just need to handle the conversion in your own code.

Comment: Good example. However, i'd recommend hard coding the version into the code. Instead of "if(dataVersion == CUR_VERSION)" use "if(dataVersion >= 5)". Otherwise when you jump to version 6, it's going to deserialize v5 data improperly.

Comment: @ldkronos - i don't understand.  if you change to version 6, then you will presumably be changing the code...

Comment: @jtahlborn - Although this example is simple, in reality you are probably going to be deserializing multiple fields from the stream. While version 5 might have affected handling of the 3rd variable, version 6 might concern handling of the 7th variable. The way the example is written, when you go to add handling for variable #7 in version 6, you first have to go back and rewrite handling of variable #3 for version >= 5. So rather than make you remember to change it later (and possibly break it), just do it correctly now, then nothing gets broken in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer to this is don't change the `serialVersionUID`.

If you think you've made a serialization-incompatible change to the class, first read the [Object Versioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) part of the Object Serialization Specification to double-check that, as you probably haven't, and if you really have, change/add the `writeObject`/`readObject` methods so that they can cope with the old serialization format.

And certainly don't try to mess around with two versions of the class at runtime. It won't work.